# Is it OK to reuse Django URL patterns. If so, how?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I have an URL and a class based view hierarchy that needs to do exactly the same thing, but for various reasons they need to have separate `dispatch()` methods in one of the superclasses.

I.e a common superclass for all of the views has a `dispatch()` method that calls `dispatchA()` if URL was `/a/...` and `dispatchB()` if URL was `/b/.../`

Is it OK to use the same pattern(...) twice in django urlpatterns() with different prefix.

For extra credit, any idea how to add a kwarg (like `b = True`) to the latter pattern so I don't have to do URL checking in the `dispatch()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly fine to do this. You can pass [extra kwargs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) by specifying them in a dictionary after the pattern:

```
(r'^a/foo/$', my_view, {'b': False}),
(r'^b/foo/$', my_view, {'b': True}),
```

Alternatively, you could capture the prefix itself as a kwarg and check that in the dispatch method.

Comment: So `(r'^a/', include(foo), dict(a=True))` should work too, right?

Comment: Sure, using it with include is explained just a bit further down on the same link above.